What formula to use for finding a sum in a table based on two criteria
I can't seem to find a formula to auto populate what car 1 done in the week of 09.06.24 and then car 2 and so and so on.
I tried the sumifs formula but got it come up with invalid answer.


Please create a [reprex]. That would include mock data, the SUMIFS formula tried, the expected result and the invalid answer you're getting, with data as a markdown table, not a screenshot.

The simplest way is to use an array formula.

=SUMPRODUCT((C2:G2=B9)*(B3:B5=B7)*C3:G5)

